# How to evaluate $\int_C {\bf{F}}\cdot d\bf{r}$ for the following surface?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, 3d, curves, vector-fields, stokes-theorem

How to evaluate $\int_C {\bf{F}}\cdot d\bf{r}$ for the following surface?

Suppose ${\bf F}(x,y,z)=xy \ {\bf i}+yz\ {\bf j}+zx\ {\bf k}$ and the $C$ is the boundary of the part of the parabloid $z=1-x^2-y^2$ in the first octant.

This question can be easily solved by applying Stoke's theorem. But what if we do not use Stoke's theorem? Is the boundary of the surface the curve that go through all $zy$, $xy$ and $xz$ planes or the one that only lies on $xy$ plane? If we have found the curve, how do we parametrize it?

[image]

Comment: You mean the boundary of the *surface*.  All three curves (those through the zy, xy, xz planes) form the boundary.

Comment: So you would basically have three curves to parametrize like :
$$
\gamma_1(t) = (t,\sqrt{1-t^2},0), \ t\in[0,1] \\
\gamma_2(t) = (t,0,1-t^2),  \ t\in[0,1] \\
\gamma_3(t) = (0,t,1-t^2), \  \ t\in[0,1]
$$
(I did these computation by head, so most likely wrong, but you get the idea :p )